# Grouping tuples using libraries in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python is there an easier way without writing bunch of loops be able to count the values in a similar way. Perhaps using some library such as itertools groupby?

```
#original tuple array
[("A","field1"),("A","field1"),("B","field1")]

#output array
[("A","field1", 2), ("B", "field1",1)]
```

Comment: So you just want the count? Try using `collections.Counter`. Have you actually *tried* `groupby`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Counter dict to group, adding the count at the end

```
l = [("A","field1"),("A","field1"),("B","field1")]


from collections import Counter


print([k+(v,) for k,v in Counter(l).items()])
```

If you want the output ordered by the first time you encounter a tuple, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to do the  counting:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for t in l:
    d.setdefault(t, 0)
    d[t] += 1

print([k+(v,) for k,v in d.items()])
```

Comment: Awesome, I like OrderedDict() it removes the need to presort the array! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Omit the `key` parameter, then it will just group equal elements (assuming those are consecutive), then add the number of elements in the group.

```
>>> lst = [("A","field1"),("A","field1"),("B","field1")]
>>> [(k + (len(list(g)),)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst)]
[('A', 'field1', 2), ('B', 'field1', 1)]
```

If the elements are not consecitive, then this will not work, and anyway, the solution suggesting [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) seems to be a better fit to the problem.

Comment: Data must be in sorted order or else this will fail

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution but the data needs to be sorted. I guess for large lists this might be slower because of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just want to count the number of ocurrences of each tuple...right? If so, you can use [Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python)

Comment: Hi Manu, yet I'm just doing a count. I want to count total of field1 that have "A" and count total field1 in "B"